# Ошибка при обновлении данных в БД Accesss

Tags: c#, sql

[image: Как так?]
Как сделать активным свойство "Обновить таблицу данных" У меня из-за него не обновляются данные в таблице. Просто на мсдн читал что для этого должны быть в наличии 2 первых пункта и внешние ключи в таблицах(е). У меня все это есть, так спрашивается какого....???

Хочу сделать нормальное добавление, изменение и удаление данных с таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Очень плохо когда поле именуется как таблица, или таблицы как поля из другой таблицы.
Пересмотрите архитектуру БД. А так, попробуйте

```
Select EnTable.En,EnTable.Id from En as EnTable
```

И по аналогии в другой таблице